# What is the probability that only one finds a parking space?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two friends, one on a bike and the other in a car, arrive together at a parking lot. The chance
that the one in the car will find a parking space is 0.1, and the one on the bike not finding a
parking space is 0.1. What is the probability that only one of them finds a parking space?

Comment: This is not a 'do my homework for free' service!

Comment: Any thoughts?  Just to say:  you (or your teacher) should specify that the events are meant to be independent (or describe the dependence). That is not realistic...after all, both depend on how crowded the parking lot is.  But without an assumption like that there's no way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one of them is able to park, then one of two things happened

- one parked the bike and the other did not park the car
- one parked the car and the other did not park the bike

Those can be computed separately and should let you arrive with ease to the final answer.

Comment: @barakmanos is it "wrong" to provide this kind of answers to this kind of questions?